# Packing some of OpenGL commands in a dynamic library, got "wglMakeCurrent failed"

Tags: c, opengl, dll, tcl

I am trying to put some of my OpenGL commands in an external library. To be specific, I'm currently drawing a 3d scene with Tcl language, and now I want to put some openGl functions (drawing functions for example) **in a dll (programmed in C)** and load it from **Tcl**. This is because I will have large quantity of data to render. With a compiled C library it will run faster.

However, I'm having problem doing so. When I launch my program, a "**wglMakeCurrent failed**" error occurs just **before the second run of my display callback** function.

Both Tcl and C parts report the **same thread ID**. So I suppose that I do not have to worry about multithreading and context sharing issue.

This is my display callback function:

```
proc DisplayCallback { toglwin } {

    # adjust camera and objects ... 

    if {[catch {set cubeList [ExternalDrawCube $::cube(size)]}]} {
        puts "Catch drawcube error !!"
    } else {
        glCallList $cubeList
    }

    $toglwin swapbuffers
}
```

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: What happens if the context you're trying to make current _already is current_? (The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd374387(v=vs.85).aspx) are unclear on this point; thanks for that, Microsoft!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the stupid bug I did in my code..

In the C function, I wrote "**glEnd**" instead of "**glEnd()**". I forgot it when converting the code from tcl!

Hopefully this would help people who have similar **wglMakeCurrent failed** error...

Good debugging for all